Database connection error only when I call await UserManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("Manager")
Im building an app, where I want it to show a list of managers when you're going to register a new user, but i'm facing a pretty annoying problem:
My database connection it's working perfectly fine, I can register new users, login, but only when i call this line of code:
await UserManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("Manager")

it returns me this error:
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
  An error occurred using the connection to database 'teste' on server 'tcp:gustavo2004.database.windows.net,1433'.

I've tried to update the database, make a new migration, and it seems like really there is no problem with my database or my connection.

Did you add  .AddRoles<IdentityRole>() to  AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>? I place it before .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().

Yes, it was the first thing I did actually, And the problem dont seem to be around the roles itself, because I was able to create users with roles with no problem, I even checked in the daatabse to see If it was being correctly saved there. The problem only happen when I call SOME funtions of the UserManager
